# Unable to initialize native-platform. on Jenkins

Tags: java, jenkins, gradle, android-studio, google-cloud-platform

I've recently set up for my first time a Jenkins environment for CI. I obviously started having problems right away. I set up the git (which seems to work very nicely) and then gradle.

When I launch a build I get this error:

```
+ gradle build
Could not load Logmanager "org.apache.juli.ClassLoaderLogManager"
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.juli.ClassLoaderLogManager
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.logging.LogManager$1.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.util.logging.LogManager.<clinit>(Unknown Source)
    at org.gradle.logging.internal.JavaUtilLoggingConfigurer.configure(JavaUtilLoggingConfigurer.java:36)
    at org.gradle.logging.internal.DefaultLoggingConfigurer.configure(DefaultLoggingConfigurer.java:34)
    at org.gradle.logging.internal.LoggingSystemAdapter.setLevel(LoggingSystemAdapter.java:55)
    at org.gradle.logging.internal.LoggingSystemAdapter.on(LoggingSystemAdapter.java:42)
    at org.gradle.logging.internal.DefaultLoggingManager$StartableLoggingSystem.start(DefaultLoggingManager.java:173)
    at org.gradle.logging.internal.DefaultLoggingManager.start(DefaultLoggingManager.java:58)
    at org.gradle.logging.internal.DefaultLoggingManager.start(DefaultLoggingManager.java:29)
    at org.gradle.launcher.cli.CommandLineActionFactory$WithLogging.execute(CommandLineActionFactory.java:201)
    at org.gradle.launcher.cli.CommandLineActionFactory$WithLogging.execute(CommandLineActionFactory.java:169)
    at org.gradle.launcher.cli.ExceptionReportingAction.execute(ExceptionReportingAction.java:33)
    at org.gradle.launcher.cli.ExceptionReportingAction.execute(ExceptionReportingAction.java:22)
    at org.gradle.launcher.Main.doAction(Main.java:33)
    at org.gradle.launcher.bootstrap.EntryPoint.run(EntryPoint.java:45)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.gradle.launcher.bootstrap.ProcessBootstrap.runNoExit(ProcessBootstrap.java:54)
    at org.gradle.launcher.bootstrap.ProcessBootstrap.run(ProcessBootstrap.java:35)
    at org.gradle.launcher.GradleMain.main(GradleMain.java:23)

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Could not create an instance of type org.gradle.invocation.DefaultGradle_Decorated.
```

Here's a full [--stacktrace --info --debug version of the error](http://pastebin.com/uuBXC0Dn).

Comment: solved. Never mind...

Comment: Mind posting your answer on here then? :) Stack is meant as a repo for good questions and answers. I don't see future users finding a solution if they have the same problem as you (unless deveshase's solution was correct)

Comment: Sorry about that. Actually the error still persists, but it doesn't stop the job to be made. The real error was in the last two rows. I used this: [link](http://www.davidandersen.us/uncategorized/gradle-libnative-platform-so-error-on-jenkins/) and installed the libnative-platform. That solved my problem!

Comment: @LucaSimonetti Great to hear that you’ve solved your issue! Can you please move your solution into an answer and [accept it](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/01/accept-your-own-answers/) so that this question is marked as closed? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The actual problem is the one in the last row:

```
* What went wrong: 
Could not create an instance of type org.gradle.invocation.DefaultGradle_Decorated.
```

I found the solution at this [link](http://www.davidandersen.us/uncategorized/gradle-libnative-platform-so-error-on-jenkins/)

Comment: As mentioned in the link above enabling ''Force GRADLE_USER_HOME to use workspace" worked for me too.

Answer (score 2):

This is a result of **-Djava.util.logging.manager=org.apache.juli.ClassLoaderLogManager** being set in the default JAVA_OPTS. This causes trouble for gradle in some environments.

Set JAVA_OPTS in the build to anything to prevent defaulting.

Also, try disabling GRADLE in your build to triage the problem.